When should I use await when using aiohttp?
I am new to python and I was studying asyncio/aiohttp but I'm kinda confused when should I use an "await".
It's clear that I use await when I want to wait the response but let's imagine the scenario: I have a post request using aiohttp that I execute and I want to get the response and add it to another dictionary:
async def post(client: aiohttp.ClientSession, url: str, mydata: Dict[str, any]):        
    async with client.post(url=url, json=mydata, headers={}) as resp:
        r = await resp.json()
        return {mydata['name']: r}

And I have my another functions that will perform mass post requests:
async def rungo(url: str, mydatas: List[Dict[str, Any]]) -> List[Dict[str, Any]]:
    tasks = []    
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        for mydata in mydatas:
            task = asyncio.create_task(coro=make_request(client=session, url=url, feature=feature))            
            tasks.append(task)

        responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

        return list(responses)

Why I need to use await 2 times? Is it right? It looks like that I will stuck my code twice.
How can I make this code performatic in a pythonic way? I am reading so many article but still confused if should be only one await or it's a common practice have many "await" in my code.

To expand on that, an async function when called just returns a coroutine object, you then need to await that to execute the function body. There's not really any performance issue with awaiting a function, it's just syntax to let you know that the code may yield to the event loop and switch context to run another task (this is what makes it so much safer than threading, see for example: https://glyph.twistedmatrix.com/2014/02/unyielding.html).
In your second example, you pass these coroutine objects to asyncio.create_task(), which causes them to be executed as separate tasks in the background. These tasks should still be awaited at a later point to ensure they have completed (and raise any exceptions if something went wrong), which you do in this example when you await asyncio.gather().
Note that asyncio.gather() can create the tasks for you, so you could simplify that code to:
await asyncio.gather(*(make_request(...) for d in mydata))

But, in short, using asyncio.gather() is exactly the correct way to make your code performant, as it will allow all those network requests to run in parallel.

It's really simple: If the thing you are calling is declared with async def then you await it.
You seem to assume that "await" implies "wait" but that's not what it does; it waits if the results are not available, but a chain of await on an await which awaits another await will not block needlessly, they will all just find "ah, the results are available already" and return immediately.
